# Apex 19.2 : Downloading file from external url into blob column

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex-19.2

I am facing hard time to achieve this.

**Requirement:**

Save file from external link into data base column on button  click.

**File Url:**

https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/autumn-forest-nature-vivid-morning-600w-766886038.jpg

I need to store this image in table blob column.

**Problem:**

I have tried using `UTL_HTTP` but due to ACL privilige and Certificate it is not working on Oracle ATP apex.

Alternatively, I am trying to search to achieve via java script however I am not able to find right links and code. Not sure whetehr it can be achived via java script or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you don't need anything else than create the Form page using the wizard.
As an example, I created a form page with a blob column. It creates a File Browser item in the page:
[image]

So, when I run the form I can enter the link of your picture:
[image]

You don't need to save the picture in advance, just enter the link of your image.